# listview fixing contents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to do my own listView with the xml file, this is what I would like to get:

[image]

And this is what I get:

[image]

And my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
 
<LinearLayout 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center"
 >       

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/parkingState" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dip" 
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:background="@null"/>


 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >    

    <TextView android:id="@+id/LblTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dip" />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/LblSubTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="12px" /> 

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >    
    
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:background="@null"/>
   
   <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:background="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I get the first image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your text linearLayout like this

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                >
```

Final:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/parkingState"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                 android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"/>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/LblTitle"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:textSize="14dip"/>


        <TextView android:id="@+id/LblSubTitle"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textStyle="normal"
                  android:textColor="#444444"
                  android:textSize="12px"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                     android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/rent"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                     android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The LinearLayout that contains @+id/LblTitle and @+id/LblSubTitle should look like this

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
```

So it will take all the remaining width and will not overlap your pictures